# Convert table look-up into function

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

Two problems: Given a known table (boolean or int), convert it to a function that returns the same value using only simple operations (and, or, xor, sum...). For example:

`bool table1[] = {0,1}` converted to `fun (int index) {return index;}`

`bool table2[] = {0,1,1,0}` converted to `fun (int index) {return index ^ (index>>1);}`

`int table3[] = {4,5,7}` converted to `fun(int index) {return index+4+(index>>1);}`

Comment: Also, what exactly is the question here? Do you want a general method? For the Boolean case, you can always use a CNF (or a DNF), though that's not necessarily the most efficient way. You can do the same for integers, using the fact that each bit in their base 2 representation is just a Boolean predicate. Again, this will often perform abysmally bad. Finally, in many situations, tables (if they are small enough) are actually faster, depending on your processor. Just time it to be sure.

Comment: Note that your example functions are incorrect. They return results for indices not present in the table. Also, I want to second Yuval in asking: what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your tables are 1-dimensional. So basically for an integer $x$ you define some value $T[x]$ and you are looking for a function $f$ such that $f(x)=T[x]$.

There is a name for the problem that tries to find a function that runs through a given set of sample points, this is known as **interpolation**. Your problem is special, since your sample points are given by $(x,T[x])$ and the $x$s are the indices of your table.

The most classical approach is to use a polynomial as a function (but there is also theory about other classes of functions). It is a well known theorem that if you have $n$ samples, then you can find a polynomial $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i x^i$ that coincides with your samples. There are different ways how determine the $n$ parameters $a_i$ of the polynomial.

One way to determine the polynomial is the method of Lagrange, you define for every index $i$ of you table the coefficient
$$L_i(x):=  \prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^{n} \frac{x-j}{i-j}.$$
If you look how $L_i(x)$ behaves on the samples, then you get
$$L_i(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x=i  \\ 0 & x= \text{table index}\not= i \end{cases}.$$

Now you can easily come up with the desired polynomial by setting
$$f(x):=\sum_{i=1}^n T[i]L_i(x).$$
You can bring $f$ in the form $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i x^i$ if you like.

Concerning you example {4,5,7}, you get $$f(x)=4 ((x - 2)/-1*(x - 3)/-2) + 5 ((x - 1)*(x - 3)/-1) + 
 7 ((x - 1)/2*(x - 2))),$$
which simplifies to 
$$f(x)=4-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}.$$

For further reading visit [the Wikipedia page on interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).

Here is a final remark. The table has in almost all cases the more compact representation, and it has the faster look-up time for sure.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what the OP wants, but it's hard to tell given the current form of the question.

Comment: @Raphael: Well, if you consider + and * as simple operations, than this solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what is being asked here.  If the table is of finite and known length, then you can do this using a polynomial regression, although that will not give you an optimal solution.  If you simply want to have any arbitrary table turned into an optimal algorithm, then you can use [genetic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming) to find the answer, although that's more of a meta-algorithm than an algorithm itself.